# Authenticating Debian against AD using only LDAP

Tags: active-directory, debian, ldap, authentication

I have been trying to set up a number of Debian machines to authenticate and authorize users against the Company AD. I am facing a problem however, the IT department will only allow connectivity against the AD's LDAP, and not against Kerberos.

I can't find any descriptions as to how to handle an LDAP only login, everything i find seems to use both LDAP and Kerberos, (Like libnss-ldap and libpam-krb5)

So i need a way, using only the AD's LDAP (Running over TLS) to authenticate a user and translate any AD groups for that user to unix groups.
Is this possible, and how?
Extra credit for deep and thorough explanations, i am not very well versed in any of these libraries, and i'm on my first attempt to integrate linux and windows machines.

Comment: I honestly think the correct answer here is to find the people in the IT department behind this dysfunctional policy and give them a high-five (in the face with a sledgehammer). It seems counter-productive to try proceeding under the current circumstances.

Comment: I agree. Let's just say that i tried that, and it didn't quite work as intended:)